# How to make a field required if it appearing on a form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a Laravel 5.8 project and on a Blade I added this:

```
    @if(empty($user->usr_name))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class='text-danger'>*</span>
                <label>Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" value="{{ !empty($user->member->mbr_mobile) ? $user->member->mbr_mobile : old('mobile') }}" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    
    @if(empty($user->usr_email))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class='text-danger'>*</span>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ !empty($user->usr_email) ? $user->usr_email : old('email') }}" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
```

So if the `usr_name` of the user is set to NULL, then the user can enter his user name.

And if the `usr_email` of the user is EMPTY, then he can enter his email address.

If one of these fields are not empty, then it won't be appeared on page.

Now I need to make these fields required as well:

```
$data = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,usr_email',
            'mobile' => 'required|unique:users,usr_name',
        ]);
```

But this is wrong, because if the user has already an username, then the required rule must be omitted and the same applies to user email.

So the question is, how to make a field required if it is appearing on a form? Otherwise it should be `nullable`.

Comment: If the field is not empty. 
- Make it disabled using the disabled tag. 
- Or hide it by adding a class dynamically.
- Or add it as a hidden field.

Comment: Consider using the [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present) validation rule.

Comment: there is also the `required_if` rule

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class='text-danger'>*</span>
            @if(empty($user->usr_name))
                <label>Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" value="{{ 
                !empty($user->member->mbr_mobile) ? $user->member->mbr_mobile : 
                old('mobile') }}"
            @elseif(empty($user->usr_email))
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ 
                !empty($user->usr_email) ? $user->usr_email : old('email') }}"
            @endif 
            required="required">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
    if($request->email){
       $data = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,usr_email',
       ]);
    } else {
       $data = $request->validate([
            'mobile' => 'required|unique:users,usr_name',
       ]);
    }
```

laravel 5 is not support anymore use 8 or higher